# Html button not working with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I created a simple app in `PhyCharm` and in my `static` folder i have a `.js` file and in my templates folder, a `index.html` file.

In my .js file, i have this:

```
console.log('loaded script.js');

$(document).ready(function () {

$("#submit").on('click', function (event) {
    handleClick();
});

});

function handleClick() {
  alert("We got here");
    $.ajax('/', {
       type: 'GET',
          data: {
          fmt: 'json'
      }
      });
   }
```

and this is the `index.html:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script src="static/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Get It">
</body>
</html>
```

when the app loads, `"loaded script.js"` shows in the console, but the button click doesn't work. Am not sure why as the code looks fine to me.

Comment: You don't seem to be loading jQuery...

Comment: Okay, so how do i load it?

Comment: @david beat me to it.. Load it the same way as you are loading your script.js file. Make sure you load them in the right order: 1. Load jQuery 2. load script.js

Comment: By referencing it in a `script` tag, just like the JavaScript file you're loading now.  Be sure to load jQuery before your file, though, since the code is processed in the order it's loaded.  If jQuery isn't referenced you *should* be getting errors in your JavaScript console.  Specifically telling you that `$` isn't defined.  That console will help you in debugging.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Comment: Thanks guys, i just added `<script src="static/jquery.js"></script>` and it worked.Phew!

Answer (score 1):

You need to load your jQuery File

**Update** You shouldn't be loading your JavaScript in your `<head>` tag. You should be loading it at the bottom of your `<body>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Get It">
<script src="static/jQuery.js"></script>
<script src="static/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it's at the bottom of the page, it loads after the page loads.Not cool if your script needs to do some background task to display on the page

Answer (score 1):

Everyone has given you the answer. This one uses Google's CDN.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script src="static/script.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"/>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Get It">
</body>
</html>
```

Refer to http://jsfiddle.net/hpX3e/ for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cluttering up your .js file with...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#submit").on('click', function (event) {
handleClick();
});

});
```

Why not simplify the entire thing by simply calling the function in the HTML.

```
<input type="button" id="submit" onclick="handleClick()" value="Get it">
```